# AngularJS - Create a directive to fire an event (function) when the current element is appended to the DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am trying to find a way to detect when an element is **finally** appended to DOM? Is there any directive that I can create and attach to that element so it will detect the moment of appending? By creating elements I mean ng-repeat,  and onload and $last do not work for me.

Comment: I'm very curious why you need to do this.  My second thought is you can usually find some sort of event fired by the browser when things like this happen so I would search there.

Comment: well I am creating the elements using angular and then I need access to those elements right after I create them so I can perform a manipulation on them, but they are not visible yet, since they are deep inside the template. $timeout works but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Why not just bind things to the view so the updates are made automatically when things in the model change?  I know this doesn't cover all scenarios but I feel like people try to shoehorn other solutions when this would work fine, unfortunately I don't have a direct answer for you though either, hopefully someone who has tried this will chime in.  Is this a scenario where a class change won't handle it (you need info from the browser about computed metrics?)

Comment: You can't always determine when the DOM is updated.  I suggest reading [Miško's comment](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/734#issuecomment-3657272).

Comment: Good read at the bottom there Igor also notes a couple of events that can one can listen for.

Comment: You could also attempt to deal with all the browsers different event systems too, it seems at least Mozilla and Chrome would allow this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver  But I would strongly consider if what you're doing in the way you're trying to do it is really correct.

Comment: Well the thing is that I am not certain if what I am trying to do is going to be done in the correct way. That is why I am looking for different opinions on what the right way is...